# convert string into pyspark.sql.types.StructType pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to create empty dataframe in pyspark where Im passing scehma from external JSON file however Json doesn't allow me to specify struct type so I had mentioned it as string.
json file :

```
"OptionalEvents" :  {
    "Event1":
      "StructType([StructField('id',StringType(), True),StructField('time',StringType(), True),StructField('ts',StringType(), True),StructField('date',StringType(), True),StructField('address',StringType(), True) ])"

  },
```

pyspark code :

```
empty_schema = json_content.get("OptionalEvents")
 schema_str = empty_schema["Event1"]
 df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[], schema=schema_str )
```

here schema_str is a string so getting error while creating data frame.
Is there any way to convert it into struct type with minimal effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal effort that you could do is by using `eval` to convert your string into objects:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

empty_schema = json_content.get("OptionalEvents")
schema_str = empty_schema["Event1"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[], schema=eval(schema_str))

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- time: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- date: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- address: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`spark.createDataFrame()` will accept schema as DDL string also.

Instead of passing StructType version and doing conversion you can pass DDL schema from file as shown below.

```
"OptionalEvents" :  {
    "Event1":
       "id string, time string, ts string, date string, address string"
  },
```